# How to lazy-load a NavigationView - Android Development

Tags: java, android

Our team is adding a Navigation Menu to our app using `NavigationView` [1]. However, loading the NavigationView takes significantly longer time to start our app. I was wondering whether it is possible to lazily load such `NavigationView`? `ViewStub` [2] seems not possible here because there seems to be no way to convert `ViewStub` to `NavigationView`.

[1] https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView
[2]
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub

Comment: Probably put most of the non-UI stuff into worker thread(s)

Comment: How long are we talking? To go with @Zain suggestion you could also put your UI stuff inside the non UI threads you will just need to post back the updates.. The goal is get `OnCreate` of your startup activity to complete as fast as possible. You can fill in the blanks as the non UI threads post their view updates.